# lookup columns and match in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an excel_1 with 4 columns (A, B, C, score) with different combinations. I have another excel_2 with 3 columns (A, B, C). I would like according A, B, C and find out score. I'm trying using excel index and match function, but i still can not figure out. without coding, it really make me trouble to match it one by one...May i know how to write code in Matlab?

Example:

```
excel_1
99 5 35 12
99 2 32 14
97 5 13 94
...

excel_2
97 5 13
99 2 32
...
```

After execute the code,

Result:

```
excel_2
97 5 13 94
99 2 32 14
...
```

Thanks a lot...

```
A = xlsread('excel_1.xlsx');
B = xlsread('excel_2.xlsx');

[~,J] = ismember(B,A(:,1:size(B,2)),'rows');
if any(J)
    result = A(J,:);
end

??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in ==> Untitled at 6
    result = A(J,:);
```

Solved. can not exist impossible between B and A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can try this.

```
[~,J] = ismember(excel_2,excel_1(:,1:size(excel_2,2)),'rows');
if any(J)
   result = excel_1(J,:);
end
```

Then

```
result =

    97     5    13    94
    99     2    32    14
```

Comment: I get the error of ??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.Error in ==> Untitled at 6 result = A(J,:);...May u know what is the reason?

Comment: the J return correct indices, however, it can not converted to the 4th column value. may i know y?